# Java code working in Intellij Idea, but not working JAR file after building artifact

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Why java code working in Intellij Idea, but not working JAR file after building artifact?
I tried changing it to "getResource (" ../ img / icon.jpg "))" and indicating the full path. It does not help.

[image]

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1CT4.jpg)

Comment: can you check if the img/icon.jpg is packaged into the jar? you can replace the extension .jar with .zip , and unzip it to verify

Comment: yes, i checked. img/icon.jpg is packaged into the jar

Comment: try use a different way of running the jar. java -cp target/your_file.jar your.package.name.YourClass

Answer (score 0):

Based on the definition of getResource() method from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

> The getResource() methods find a resource with a given name. The rules
>   for searching for resources associated with a given class are
>   implemented by the class's ClassLoader.

it delegates to the ClassLoader to load the resource, and ClassLoader will find the resource through the classpath.

in that case, you may try to specify the classpath in your command to verify

```
 java -cp target/your_file.jar your.package.name.YourClass
```

Comment: C:\Users\akala\IdeaProjects\MemoryGame\out\artifacts\Memory_Game_jar>java -cp target/"Memory Game.jar" "Memory Game".Game
Error: Could not find or load main class Memory Game.Game
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Memory Game.Game https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1CT4.jpg

Comment: C:\Users\akala\IdeaProjects\MemoryGame\out\artifacts\Memory_Game_jar>java -cp "Memory Game.jar" Game

Comment: no, it's not working. Now, I added maven to the project. Made a package. The jar have got the img folder. but it not helped

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was that the file was called "icon.**JPG**", but in the code "icon.**jpg**". For some reason, this worked when launched in the IDE, and did not work in the JAR.